# Excel VBA: Use a sheet from the same workbook?

Tags: vba, excel

**The scenario:** I have an Excel workbook with a macro that uses a template (from "`C:\Users\User1\Desktop\1.xltx`") to create customized sheets.

**The problem:** I need to make Excel to use the template from the same workbook - I have added the template as a separate sheet ("temp1"). I can't seem to figure it out, even though it's probably very simple.

**The current code:**

```
 Set wks = Sheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count), Type:="C:\Users\User1\Desktop\1.xltx")
```

Comment: If you have access to that user's desktop folder then that code should work. I just set up a similar environment and had no problem adding a worksheet based upon the single worksheet in an .XLTX file located on my own desktop. Was the template file saved as an Excel Template or was a regular workbook simply renamed as an .xltx?

Comment: @Jeeped I do have access, but the file will be used on many computers and I will have to change the directory every time, AND I will have to send over multiple files to every computer. The template was an Excel Template, but is there no way to use a sheet on the same workbook as a template instead?

Comment: Have a look at my response in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31370531/excel-vba-splitting-data-into-report-table). I leave a single worsheet in the workbook as xlVeryHidden and use it to create new worksheets for preformatted reports.

Comment: @Jeeped I feel dumb... I've been trying to make this work for 20 minutes and nothing went right. I tried looking at the code in your worksheet but I'm pretty sure I've been looking at the wrong code. Is there no way to set "Type:="C:\Users\User1\Desktop\1.xltx" to link directly to the sheet?

Comment: Now it's my turn to be confused. Yes, you could use `environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\1.xltx"` to refer to each user's desktop but then you would have to distribute the template workbook to each user and I thought that was undesirable. Probably better just to have a hidden worksheet in the coded workbook that acts like a template and let the code create new worksheets from that.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want individual copies of the template for each user. If something on the template changes, you would have to update every copy.

Have you thought of talking to your SysAdmin and storing the template (1.xltx) in a common location with Read Only permission for the users?